# label option in tikz-cd influences distance between column

Tags: labels, columns, tikz-cd

I want to give one node a label using `tikz-cd`. But then it seems that when arrange column distance, `tikz` takes the label node as a part of the main node rather than only considers the size of main node.

So I want `tikz-cd` to ignore the existence of label node when arrange column distance. Is there some option to do this?

Here is my codes. Here I have a big label distance to make the distance easy to be distinguished.

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=2em,label distance=2em]
\circ\rar &|[label=left:2]|\circ\rar &\circ
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

Of course, one can use `tikzpicture` directly. Compare with using `\matrix` in `tikzpicture`.

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=2em]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep=2em]{
\node (1){\circ};
&\node (2)[label=left:2]{\circ};
&\node (3){\circ};\\ };
\path[->] (1) edge (2)
          (2) edge (3);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
```

Or, if load `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`, one can try

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}
[label distance=1em]
\node (3)  {$\circ$};
\node (2) [left=of 3,label=left:2] {$\circ$};
\node (1) [left=of 2] {$\circ$};
\path[->] (1) edge (2)
          (2) edge (3);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
```

Here, `tikz` ignores the label node when position main nodes.

[image]

Of course when use `\node (2) at (1,0) [label=left:2]{$\circ$}`, there is no problem. But when the size of main node change, one need to compute the coordinate by hand.

So, I am wondering why does not `tikz-cd` ignore the label node when position main nodes; as one can see, `tikzpicture` can do this. And is there some option can tell `tikz-cd` to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be labelling the arrow not the node.  If you do that you will see the `\rar` shorthand has a bug when `sep` is specified and you need to use the full `\arrow`.  By the way, `sep` is not a dimension, but a key word such as `large`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I really want to label the node. Here I make the label so far from the main node since I want to make the effect to be easy to observe; that is when position columns, `tikz` sees the label nodes as a part of main nodes, and when position arrows, `tikz` only considers the main nodes. Besides, these codes work for me. Maybe, you need to update the `tikz` package?

Comment: The `tikz-cd` is built on a matrix of nodes, which exhibits the same behaviour with respect to added labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a label, you can draw a node at the desired position afterward, with the option `execute at end picture={,,,}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    sep=2em,
    every matrix/.append style={name=mymatr},
    execute at end picture={
        \node[left=2em of mymatr-1-2.east] {2}; 
        }
    ]
    \circ\rar &\circ\rar &\circ
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]